# videos not playing in Flowplayer after configuring mod deflate

Tags: apache, .htaccess, flowplayer, mod-deflate

I configured Apache/2.2.17 server  on Windows 7 with mod deflate configured in .htaccess as

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ \
no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
 \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ \
no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

But everything worked fine except videos were not playing in Flowplayer so I changed (added SWF in exclude from gzip compression  )  in .htaccess to

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ \
no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
 \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar|swf)$ \
no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.pdf$ no-gzip dont-vary
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Now the video plays in flowplayer in all browsers except IE.

I want correct configuration to work in IE also.

Comment: Try using the code from the html5boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/template/htaccess.txt

Comment: Thanks @Gerben it worked.I will add the working configuration as answer.

Comment: Great. Please mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark next to your answer. CU

Comment: Sure I will do this but its says that I can accept my own answer after two days .If you post your comment as answer I will mark it answered now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following config worked.

```
# force deflate for mangled headers 
# developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping/
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$   ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# HTML, TXT, CSS, JavaScript, JSON, XML, HTC:
<IfModule filter_module>
 FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
 FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
 FilterChain     COMPRESS
 FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
 # Legacy versions of Apache
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml    application/atom+xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
 </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
```